# dfs algorithms uses queue?

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

i have seen in internet following  DFS  algorithm

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

queue<int> myQueue;
int G[MAX][MAX];
int visit[MAX];
int V, E;


void dfs(int s) {
     int i, j, node;
     memset(visit, 0, sizeof(visit));
     myQueue.push(s);

     while(!myQueue.empty())
     {
          node = myQueue.front();
          myQueue.pop();
          if(visit[node]) continue;
          visit[node] = 1;
          cout << node << " ";

          for(i=0; i<V; i++)
               if(G[i][node]) myQueue.push(i);
          for(j=0; j<V; j++)
               if(G[node][j]) myQueue.push(j);     
     }

}

int main() {
    memset(visit, 0, sizeof(visit));
    dfs(0);
    return 0;
}
```

my question is that it uses  queue instead of stack,  so is it correct?also  when i  should  enter graph,should it be like  adjacent matrix or?please help me,this algorithm uses default values,so how can i change  it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting.  I found the code you are referring to http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid1107E4F79ED191B482853E3206A2F13FC77B4310.aspx.

Sure enough that uses the [`queue` class from the Standard C++ Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/) and, as such, implements a **breadth-first search** algorithm.  Using a [C++ stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/) should give you the depth-first search you desire.

Goes to show you can't trust everything you see on the Internet (perhaps even including this answer). :-)

As to your second question, this posted code is indeed using an adjacency matrix.  In fact, you can even be more precise and say, by inspecting the code, that it is implementing a **undirected graph without parallel edges**.

**ADDENDUM**

The code in action, showing it is a BFS: http://ideone.com/mLl23

Comment: so instead  of queue,if i use stack,it would be correct yes?and graph i  should interpret as adjacent matrix yes?

Comment: Yes and yes.  Added to the answer.

Comment: @dato I have proved that indeed this is a breadth-first search algorithm.  See http://ideone.com/mLl23.  The output shows 0 1 3 2 which is clearly a BFS.  If it were a DFS it would have been 0 1 2 3.  Hope it is useful to you.  Try it with a stack instead and see how it goes. :-)